# XML Children Nodes

Tags: php, xml

This is my XML file:

```
<gamesList>
   <ID1>00000000000</ID1>
   <ID>USER</ID>
   <games>
      <game>
         <appID>000000</appID>
         <name>Dead Rising 3</name>
         <logo></logo>
         <storeLink></storeLink>  
         <hoursLast2Weeks>7.2</hoursLast2Weeks>
         <hoursOnRecord>7.2</hoursOnRecord>
         <statsLink></statsLink>
         <globalStatsLink></globalStatsLink>
      </game>
      <game>
         <appID>000000</appID>
         <name>Dead Rising 3</name>
         <logo></logo>
         <storeLink></storeLink>  
         <hoursLast2Weeks>7.2</hoursLast2Weeks>
         <hoursOnRecord>7.2</hoursOnRecord>
         <statsLink></statsLink>
         <globalStatsLink></globalStatsLink>
      </game>
   </games>
</gameslist>
```

I'm trying to get the 'name' and 'appID' sections of the XML. There will be up to 200+ items in the list.

I tried doing

```
foreach($xml->children() as $child)
    echo $child['name'];
```

and it didn't work.

I've never worked with PHP in this way, so I have literally no idea how or what way to start this.

Comment: You find the basic usage of how SimpleXMLElement actually works in the PHP manual here: [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). You basically did some mistakes, most likely because of not having the introduction on how to use SimpleXMLElement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('my.xml');

foreach($xml->games->game as $game) {
    print $game->name;
    print $game->appID;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"name" isn't a child's property, but a child element itself, so it would be

```
foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
  if($child->getName() == 'name') {
    $name = $child['name'];
    echo $name->__toString();
  }
}
```